# NSPopUpButton is not updated with image when an NSMenuItem is selected

Tags: macos, nspopupbutton, nspopupbuttoncell

I am having an NSPopUpButton with pullDown and added few menu items(image and title) to the menu and added that menu to the Button cell.

Initially I am assigning the First menu item of the menu to Button cell to display in NSPopUpButton.

When I tapped the NSPopUpButton a menu is displayed with all the items I added earlier and when I select an item from the menu its data is not updated to NSPopUpButton. i.e is title is getting updated and the image is not..

Can anyone suggest me how can I resolve this

The code I written :

```
In ButtonCell class:

NSMenu* newMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
    [newMenu setAutoenablesItems:YES];
    [[self optionMenuController] insertItemsInMenu:newMenu atIndex:0];
    if(isFromSetOption)
    {
        [self setMenuItem:[newMenu itemAtIndex:1]];
        isFromSetOption = NO;
    }
    //[newMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"dummy" action:nil keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
    [self setMenu:newMenu];

    [newMenu release];

In OptionMenuController :
- (void) insertItemsInMenu:(NSMenu*)menu atIndex:(NSInteger)insertIndex
{
    for( NSMenuItem* item in [self createMenuItems] )
    {
        [menu insertItem:item atIndex:insertIndex++];
    }
}
- (NSMenuItem*) menuItemForOption:(AMOptionMenuItem*)option inGroup:(AMOptionMenuItem*)group
{
    NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[option title] action:@selector(optionChosen:) keyEquivalent:@""];

    [menuItem setIndentationLevel:1];
    [menuItem setTarget:self];
    [menuItem setEnabled:YES];
    [menuItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:[option imageTitle]]];
  /*  if([[option identifier] isEqualToString:@"Color"])
    {
        [menuItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"cabinet"]];
    }
    else{
        [menuItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"YieldIcon.png"]];
    }
    */


    NSString* keypath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.is%@", [group identifier], [option identifier]];
    [menuItem setRepresentedObject:keypath];

    NSDictionary *bindingOptions = nil;
    [menuItem bind:@"value" toObject:self withKeyPath:keypath options:bindingOptions];

    return [menuItem autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're trying to use.

Comment: I edited the post and you see the code I written.

Comment: So you've subclassed `NSPopUpButton`?  Are you sure you needed to do that?

Comment: Yes I need the Subcalssing of NSPopUpButton and NSPopUpButtonCell.

Comment: That's almost certainly where the error lies; subclassing button cells is non-trivial.

Comment: So whats the difference in actual and subclassing the button and adding new functionalities wont effect the actual behaviour .. am I right?